# how to make animate with shapes in css and jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to make this shapes like picture models. Its have animation mode too.
I have 3 broblem. If I use Triangle for top of the col for corners , I need to make Border-left for Line... I wanted use this code:

[Opening from center to top and down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBOfx.jpg)

[have like triangle in top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L07h2.jpg)

[all are open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXR0B.jpg)

```css
#triangle-bottomright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    }
```

1- how to make Triangle then only give border to it for Line in top?

2- how to make animation SlideDown and SlideUp together from center?

sorry If my english is not good.pls click on links to open images.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hey, this is a great question.

There are a lot of different ways to do something like this. You could use a JS plugin like [GreenSock's MorphSVG](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/MorphSVGPlugin). But I would encourage you to take the time to learn how to animate HTML with CSS directly. There are so many different front-end use cases where you'll be able to make something like this very easily when you understand what's happening.

#### I think the cleanest way to do what you're looking to do, would be to:

1. Put 3 extra `<span>` tags inside your containers.
2. Style the `<span>` tags to their final positions.
3. Then animate the `<span>`'s by targeting the `:hover` selector of your container, and use [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to manipulate the height/width of the `<span>`'s.

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tubstrr/ney9ux01/198/) to showcase how to do this, and I've added a few comments in the SCSS to explain what's happening.

Another great resource to understand the basics of CSS animations is [this video](https://youtu.be/HZHHBwzmJLk) by FireshipIO.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): _"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link**, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline."_ - which in this case would be the actual code to achieve what OP asks for.